# How to extract the 10 days interval closest to a data specified in another column r

Tags: r, lubridate

I have a data of repeated measurements by day (like a glucose monitor). Each individual can have wear the device during period of times, so an individual can have repeated measurements for 1 week and others for 6 months.
Then each individual will have a column with a visit date. Some individuals can have more than one visit (tops 3 visits).

My data looks like this (apologies but I don't know how to generate a simulated data)

```
datos

id  visit_Date   time                 value
1   2020-03-06   2022-03-23 17:09:00  10    
1   2020-03-06   2022-03-23 17:14:00  11   
1   2020-03-06   2022-03-23 17:19:00  11   
1   2020-03-06   2022-03-23 17:24:00  12   
1   2020-03-06   2022-03-23 17:29:00  11   
2   2018-03-30   2022-03-24 17:22:00  13   
2   2018-03-30   2022-03-24 17:27:00  10
2   2018-03-30   2022-03-24 17:32:00  11
2   2018-03-30   2022-03-24 17:37:00  12
```

Some individuals can wear the monitoring device before the `visit_Date` and others wear the monitor only after the `visit_Date`. What I need it is to extract the `id, visit_Date`, `time`, and `value` in an interval of 10 days but closest to the `visit_Date`. Ideally it should be after the **visit date** but some individuals don't wear it long enough after the visit, in that case, an interval overlapping the `visit_Date` should be fine.

What I have done so far it is getting the closest date by grouping by `id` and `visit_Date`, arranging by descending `time` and then filtering by `time + 10 days`. Here is the code I am using:

```
library(lubridate)

datos %>% 
   dplyr::filter(time >= visit_Date) %>%
   group_by(id, visit_Date) %>%
   arrange(desc(time)) %>%
   dplyr::filter(time < time + 10) %>%
   summarise(min = min(time), max = max(time))
```

I am using summarise to see how many days I get in total after filtering, however this filtering is only for `time` after the visit date, and some individuals don't wear the device for 10 days after the visit. I guess I could repeat the same filtering process for **`time <= visit_Date`** for those individuals with less than 10 days, and then merge both datasets but I was wondering if there is another way of doing it

### EDIT

My desired output will be all the rows for each individual with the 10 interval days closest to the `visit_Date`, ideally after `visit_Date` but if not overlapping `visit_Date`. Here it is an example output (bear in mind that my real date has in the column `time` a data point for every 5 minutes.

Desired output (example with 2 individuals)

```
> datos

id  visit_Date   time                 value
1   2020-03-06   2022-02-22 17:09:00  10    
1   2020-03-06   2022-02-26 17:09:00  10    
1   2020-03-06   2022-02-26 17:14:00  11   
1   2020-03-06   2022-02-28 17:19:00  11   
1   2020-03-06   2022-03-07 17:24:00  12   
1   2020-03-06   2022-03-07 17:29:00  11   
2   2018-03-30   2022-03-24 17:22:00  13   
2   2018-03-30   2022-03-30 17:27:00  10
2   2018-03-30   2022-04-10 17:32:00  11
2   2018-03-30   2022-04-24 17:37:00  12
2   2018-03-30   2022-04-26 17:37:00  12

# Desired output

id  visit_Date   time                 value
1   2020-03-06   2022-02-26 17:09:00  10    
1   2020-03-06   2022-02-26 17:14:00  11   
1   2020-03-06   2022-02-28 17:19:00  11   
1   2020-03-06   2022-03-07 17:24:00  12   
1   2020-03-06   2022-03-07 17:29:00  11   
2   2018-03-30   2022-03-30 17:27:00  10
2   2018-03-30   2022-04-10 17:32:00  11
```

In this example, the individual *id1* didn't wear the device longer than 10 days after the visit date, so the output should include date from before the visit but only the 10 days-interval closest to the `visit_Date`. In the case of *id2* the individual wore the device longer than 10 days after the `visit_Date` and we select the 10 days closest to the `visit_Date` but after or equal to `visit_Date`

Thanks

Comment: Just to be sure, you want to get a single value from each individual, that is the closest to `visit_Date` + 10 days, but not after that. Is that it?

Comment: The visit dates are in 2020 and 2018 for ids 1 and 2 respectively, but the times are in 2022. Is it 10 days as total difference in time, or calendar days without considering year?

Comment: Additionally, the difference between 30 March and 10 April is at least 11 days I think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an *id*, we can check if `difftime` from `visit_date` exceeds ten days. If so we can easily subset by those values that are `TRUE`. Else, conversely we do this for differences greater that minus ten days.

```
> by(dat, dat$id, \(x) {
+   if (any(d10 <- difftime(x$visit_Date, as.Date(x$time), unit='days') > 10)) {
+     x[d10, ]
+   } else {
+     x[difftime(x$visit_Date, as.Date(x$time), unit='days') > -10, ]
+   }
+ }) |> do.call(what='rbind')
      id          visit_Date                time value   u
1.1    1 2022-01-01 02:27:41 2022-01-01 02:27:41    12   0
1.2    1 2022-01-01 02:27:41 2022-01-01 14:27:41    12   0
1.3    1 2022-01-01 02:27:41 2022-01-02 02:27:41    12   0
1.4    1 2022-01-01 02:27:41 2022-01-02 14:27:41    10   0
1.5    1 2022-01-01 02:27:41 2022-01-03 02:27:41    13   0
1.6    1 2022-01-01 02:27:41 2022-01-03 14:27:41    10   0
1.7    1 2022-01-01 02:27:41 2022-01-04 02:27:41    10   0
1.8    1 2022-01-01 02:27:41 2022-01-04 14:27:41    12   0
1.9    1 2022-01-01 02:27:41 2022-01-05 02:27:41    10   0
1.10   1 2022-01-01 02:27:41 2022-01-05 14:27:41    12   0
1.11   1 2022-01-01 02:27:41 2022-01-06 02:27:41    11   0
1.12   1 2022-01-01 02:27:41 2022-01-06 14:27:41    12   0
1.13   1 2022-01-01 02:27:41 2022-01-07 02:27:41    12   0
1.14   1 2022-01-01 02:27:41 2022-01-07 14:27:41    10   0
1.15   1 2022-01-01 02:27:41 2022-01-08 02:27:41     9   0
1.16   1 2022-01-01 02:27:41 2022-01-08 14:27:41    10   0
1.17   1 2022-01-01 02:27:41 2022-01-09 02:27:41    12   0
1.18   1 2022-01-01 02:27:41 2022-01-09 14:27:41    13   0
1.19   1 2022-01-01 02:27:41 2022-01-10 02:27:41    11   0
1.20   1 2022-01-01 02:27:41 2022-01-10 14:27:41    11   0
1.21   1 2022-01-01 02:27:41 2022-01-11 02:27:41    10   0
1.22   1 2022-01-01 02:27:41 2022-01-11 14:27:41    11   0
2.26   2 2022-12-04 17:21:57 2022-12-01 17:21:57    11  -3
2.27   2 2022-12-04 17:21:57 2022-12-02 05:21:57    11  -3
2.28   2 2022-12-04 17:21:57 2022-12-02 17:21:57    11  -3
2.29   2 2022-12-04 17:21:57 2022-12-03 05:21:57    11  -3
2.30   2 2022-12-04 17:21:57 2022-12-03 17:21:57    10  -3
2.31   2 2022-12-04 17:21:57 2022-12-04 05:21:57    12  -3
2.32   2 2022-12-04 17:21:57 2022-12-04 17:21:57    11  -3
2.33   2 2022-12-04 17:21:57 2022-12-05 05:21:57    12  -3
2.34   2 2022-12-04 17:21:57 2022-12-05 17:21:57    12  -3
2.35   2 2022-12-04 17:21:57 2022-12-06 05:21:57    13  -3
2.36   2 2022-12-04 17:21:57 2022-12-06 17:21:57    12  -3
2.37   2 2022-12-04 17:21:57 2022-12-07 05:21:57    10  -3
2.38   2 2022-12-04 17:21:57 2022-12-07 17:21:57    10  -3
2.39   2 2022-12-04 17:21:57 2022-12-08 05:21:57    12  -3
2.40   2 2022-12-04 17:21:57 2022-12-08 17:21:57    12  -3
2.41   2 2022-12-04 17:21:57 2022-12-09 05:21:57    13  -3
2.42   2 2022-12-04 17:21:57 2022-12-09 17:21:57    12  -3
2.43   2 2022-12-04 17:21:57 2022-12-10 05:21:57    10  -3
2.44   2 2022-12-04 17:21:57 2022-12-10 17:21:57    10  -3
2.45   2 2022-12-04 17:21:57 2022-12-11 05:21:57    10  -3
2.46   2 2022-12-04 17:21:57 2022-12-11 17:21:57    12  -3
2.47   2 2022-12-04 17:21:57 2022-12-12 05:21:57    10  -3
2.48   2 2022-12-04 17:21:57 2022-12-12 17:21:57    10  -3
2.49   2 2022-12-04 17:21:57 2022-12-13 05:21:57     9  -3
2.50   2 2022-12-04 17:21:57 2022-12-13 17:21:57     9  -3
3.51   3 2022-01-31 11:13:21 2022-01-28 11:13:21    12  -3
3.52   3 2022-01-31 11:13:21 2022-01-28 23:13:21    13  -3
3.53   3 2022-01-31 11:13:21 2022-01-29 11:13:21    11  -3
3.54   3 2022-01-31 11:13:21 2022-01-29 23:13:21    12  -3
3.55   3 2022-01-31 11:13:21 2022-01-30 11:13:21    11  -3
3.56   3 2022-01-31 11:13:21 2022-01-30 23:13:21    10  -3
3.57   3 2022-01-31 11:13:21 2022-01-31 11:13:21    11  -3
3.58   3 2022-01-31 11:13:21 2022-01-31 23:13:21    13  -3
3.59   3 2022-01-31 11:13:21 2022-02-01 11:13:21    11  -3
3.60   3 2022-01-31 11:13:21 2022-02-01 23:13:21    10  -3
3.61   3 2022-01-31 11:13:21 2022-02-02 11:13:21    10  -3
3.62   3 2022-01-31 11:13:21 2022-02-02 23:13:21    11  -3
3.63   3 2022-01-31 11:13:21 2022-02-03 11:13:21    12  -3
3.64   3 2022-01-31 11:13:21 2022-02-03 23:13:21    10  -3
3.65   3 2022-01-31 11:13:21 2022-02-04 11:13:21     9  -3
3.66   3 2022-01-31 11:13:21 2022-02-04 23:13:21    11  -3
3.67   3 2022-01-31 11:13:21 2022-02-05 11:13:21    12  -3
3.68   3 2022-01-31 11:13:21 2022-02-05 23:13:21    11  -3
3.69   3 2022-01-31 11:13:21 2022-02-06 11:13:21    10  -3
3.70   3 2022-01-31 11:13:21 2022-02-06 23:13:21    11  -3
3.71   3 2022-01-31 11:13:21 2022-02-07 11:13:21    13  -3
3.72   3 2022-01-31 11:13:21 2022-02-07 23:13:21    11  -3
3.73   3 2022-01-31 11:13:21 2022-02-08 11:13:21    10  -3
3.74   3 2022-01-31 11:13:21 2022-02-08 23:13:21    11  -3
3.75   3 2022-01-31 11:13:21 2022-02-09 11:13:21    13  -3
4.76   4 2022-03-01 01:40:46 2022-02-17 01:40:46    10 -12
4.77   4 2022-03-01 01:40:46 2022-02-17 13:40:46     9 -12
4.78   4 2022-03-01 01:40:46 2022-02-18 01:40:46    10 -12
4.79   4 2022-03-01 01:40:46 2022-02-18 13:40:46    10 -12
4.80   4 2022-03-01 01:40:46 2022-02-19 01:40:46    10 -12
4.81   4 2022-03-01 01:40:46 2022-02-19 13:40:46    10 -12
5.101  5 2022-07-23 18:27:11 2022-07-11 18:27:11    12 -12
5.102  5 2022-07-23 18:27:11 2022-07-12 06:27:11     9 -12
5.103  5 2022-07-23 18:27:11 2022-07-12 18:27:11    11 -12
5.104  5 2022-07-23 18:27:11 2022-07-13 06:27:11    11 -12
5.105  5 2022-07-23 18:27:11 2022-07-13 18:27:11    11 -12
```

### Update

If you want to group `by` both *id* and *visit_Date*, you are looking for the `interaction`.

```
> by(dat, with(dat, interaction(id, visit_Date)), \(x) {
+   if (any(d10 <- difftime(x$visit_Date, as.Date(x$time), unit='days') > 10)) {
+     x[d10, ]
+   } else {
+     x[difftime(x$visit_Date, as.Date(x$time), unit='days') > -10, ]
+   }
+ }) |> do.call(what='rbind')
```

---

*Data:*

Simulated data for a random date in 2022, added 12 days and randomly subtracted 3, 0 or 12 days. left the `u` column in example data for orientation. Instead of 5 min intervals I used 12 hours for sake of brevity.

```
set.seed(42)
dat <- lapply(seq_len(5), \(x) {
  visit_Date <- as.POSIXct(sample.int(31535700, 1), origin='2022-01-01')
  rnd <- runif(1L)
  if (rnd > .66) {
    u <- -3
  } else if (rnd > .33) {
    u <- 0
  } else {
    u <- -12
  }
  time <- seq.POSIXt(visit_Date, visit_Date + 12*60*60*24, by='12 hour') +
    u*60*60*24
  list(id=x,
       visit_Date=visit_Date, 
       time=time,
       value=round(runif(length(time), 9, 13)),
       u=u)
}) |> lapply(data.frame) |> do.call(what='rbind')
```

Gives

```
> by(dat, ~id, tail, 3)
id: 1
   id          visit_Date                time value   u
23  1 2022-02-07 03:52:21 2022-02-06 03:52:21    11 -12
24  1 2022-02-07 03:52:21 2022-02-06 15:52:21    11 -12
25  1 2022-02-07 03:52:21 2022-02-07 03:52:21    13 -12
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
id: 2
   id          visit_Date                time value  u
48  2 2022-03-24 14:17:57 2022-04-01 15:17:57    12 -3
49  2 2022-03-24 14:17:57 2022-04-02 03:17:57     9 -3
50  2 2022-03-24 14:17:57 2022-04-02 15:17:57    12 -3
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
id: 3
   id          visit_Date                time value   u
73  3 2022-09-26 17:29:28 2022-09-25 17:29:28    10 -12
74  3 2022-09-26 17:29:28 2022-09-26 05:29:28    10 -12
75  3 2022-09-26 17:29:28 2022-09-26 17:29:28    12 -12
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
id: 4
    id          visit_Date                time value   u
98   4 2022-04-29 20:09:16 2022-04-28 20:09:16     9 -12
99   4 2022-04-29 20:09:16 2022-04-29 08:09:16    11 -12
100  4 2022-04-29 20:09:16 2022-04-29 20:09:16    12 -12
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
id: 5
    id          visit_Date                time value u
123  5 2022-03-17 11:28:55 2022-03-28 12:28:55     9 0
124  5 2022-03-17 11:28:55 2022-03-29 00:28:55    12 0
125  5 2022-03-17 11:28:55 2022-03-29 12:28:55    11 0
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the solution. Could you please tell me if it is possible to group by id and for visit_Date at the same time. It could be that some people have two or three different visits!!

Comment: @user2380782 Yes, could you check the update please?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a data.table solution. I don't come to the same answers because of some inconsistencies in your question, but it's easy to change if you can clarify how to think about time a little bit.

```r
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(
  id = c(rep(1, 6),
                 rep(2, 5)),
  visit_Date = lubridate::as_datetime(c(
    rep("2020-03-06", 6),
    rep("2018-03-30", 5)
  )),
  time = lubridate::as_datetime(
    c(
      "2020-02-22 17:09:00",
      "2020-02-26 17:09:00",
      "2020-02-26 17:14:00",
      "2020-02-28 17:19:00",
      "2020-03-07 17:24:00",
      "2020-03-07 17:29:00",
      "2018-03-24 17:22:00",
      "2018-03-30 17:27:00",
      "2018-04-10 17:32:00",
      "2018-04-24 17:37:00",
      "2018-04-26 17:37:00"
    )
  ),
  value = c(10, 10, 11, 11, 12, 11, 13, 10, 11, 12, 12)
)
```

First you calculate the time difference (in days) between time and visit date.

```r
dt[, days_past_visit := lubridate::time_length(time - visit_Date, "days"), id]
```

Then you calculate the maximum time after the last visit date per person.

```r
dt[, max_time_followed := max(days_past_visit), id]
```

This allows you to establish how much of a buffer you need for going backwards in time for the cases where you don't follow them for ten days after the visit.  `pmin()` here replaces the days where there is no negative buffer necessary with a zero.

```r
dt[, backwards_buffer := pmin(max_time_followed - 10, 0)]
```

Then you select those measurements that meet your requirement. They must be not more distant than 10 days in the future, and they must not be further away than the remaining backwards buffer.

```r
dt[days_past_visit <= 10 & days_past_visit > backwards_buffer]

# or

dt[between(days_past_visit, lower = backwards_buffer, upper = 10)]
```